# Django Cache-Machine cache invalidation does not work in admin

Tags: python, django, caching, cache-invalidation, django-cache-machine

I installed cache-machine for my Django 1.6 project as described here: http://cache-machine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Now in django's admin, I cannot see new entries anymore. Cache invalidation does not work. I can see that the entry is beeing generated in the DB, but it does not show up in admin's list-view. What am I doing wrong?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

django-cache-machine caches count queries apart from regular model queries. You have different methods described in the documentation to workaround this:

http://cache-machine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#count-queries

The tricky part is to know that new entries don't appear because of this, but I hope your problem is solved with this.